# How to handle null value in string concatenation?

Tags: powerbuilder

I understand in PB that if there's a null value in variable concatenation then all the variable would return a null value. I'm trying to figure out if there's a way in handling the null values during the concatenation.

See example below, ls_element3 returns a null value then definitely all the variables will return a  null value, what i want to happen is to return the values under ls_element1 and ls_element2. Anybody has an idea on how to handle the null values during string concatenation?

```
String ls_message, 
ls_element1 = a, 
ls_element2 = b, 
ls_element3 = null

ls_message = ls_element1 + ls_element2 + ls_element3
```

Comment: It is not fully clear to me what you mean that all variables return null value. As far as I know only ls_message will be null. I think you could write a small function (similar to TSQL IsNull) where you can check the null value and return empty string instead. With that way the result won't be null.

Answer (score 2):

I can picture two basic approaches, although I'm sure there are several more.

```
// insert between assignment and concatenation
IF IsNull (ls_element1) THEN ls_element1 = ""
IF IsNull (ls_element2) THEN ls_element2 = ""
IF IsNull (ls_element3) THEN ls_element3 = ""
```

or

```
//create a function that mimics the if() DataWindow function in PowerScript
function string f_if (boolean ab_Condition, string as_TrueResult, string as_FalseResult)
IF ab_Condition THEN
   RETURN as_TrueResult
ELSE
   RETURN as_FalseResult
END IF
```

and change your concatenation to

```
ls_message = f_if (IsNull (ls_element1), "", ls_element1) + &
   f_if (IsNull (ls_element2), "", ls_element2) + &
   f_if (IsNull (ls_element3), "", ls_element3)
```

Good luck,

Terry

Answer (score 0):

You can coerce the null string value to an empty string via the `string()` function and the `[general]` format. It will replace a null value by an empty string:

```
string ls_a, ls_b, ls_c, ls_d

ls_a = "foo"
setnull(ls_b)
ls_c = "bar"

ls_d = string(ls_a, "[general]") + string(ls_b, "[general]") + string(ls_c, "[general]")
//ls_d is "foobar"
```

`string(variable, '[general]')` is equivalent to the `isnull(variable, '')`

But this is not some pretty code though...

Answer (score 0):

That is exactly what you need: http://forum.powerbuilder.us/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=5

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function `nullisblank(s)`. If the value passed is NULL, it returns the empty string. Otherwise it returns the value. This is especially useful in DataWindows.

Answer (score 0):

```
if not isnull(ls_element1) then ls_message += ls_element1;
if not isnull(ls_element2) then ls_message += ls_element2;
if not isnull(ls_element3) then ls_message += ls_element3
```

If you have something like this:

```
string a = '1';
string b = '';
string c = null;
```

When you make a string witch is = a + b the result would be 1
But if you make a string = a + b + c or a + c it will be = null becouse null string eleminates the value of others.